# String Matching with newline character in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

Here I am trying to find the index of '-' followed by '}' in a String.

For an input like `sustringIndex "abcd -} sad"` it gives me an output of `10`
which is giving me the entire string length.

Also if I do something like `sustringIndex "abcd\n -} sad"` it gives me `6`

Why is that so with \n. What am I doing wrong. Please correct me I'm a noob.

```
substrIndex :: String -> Int
substrIndex ""=0
substrIndex (s:"") = 0
substrIndex (s:t:str)
  | s== '-' && t == '}' = 0
  | otherwise = 2+(substrIndex str)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has a bug. You are checking every two characters. But, what if the `-` and `}` are in different pairs, for example `S-}`?

1. It will first check `S` and `-` are equal to `-` and `}` respectively.
2. Since they don't match, it will move on with `}` alone.

So, you just need to change the logic a little bit, like this

```
substrIndex (s:t:str)
  | s == '-' && t == '}' = 0
  | otherwise = 1 + (substrIndex (t:str))
```

Now, if the current pair doesn't match `-}`, then just skip the first character and proceed with the second character, `substrIndex (t:str)`. So, if `S-` doesn't match, your program will proceed with `-}`. Since we dropped only one character we add only `1`, instead of `2`.

---

This can be shortened and written clearly, as suggested by user2407038, like this

```
substrIndex :: String -> Int
substrIndex [] = 0
substrIndex ('-':'}':_) = 0
substrIndex (_:xs) = 1 + substrIndex xs
```

Comment: Oh mybad. I feel miserable looking at what I did .

Comment: I would recommend writing this function using pattern matching; it is just much nicer and shorter: `substrIndex ('-':'}':_) = 0; substrIndex (_:xs) = 1 + substrIndex xs; substrIndex [] = 0`

Comment: @user2407038 I was coming up with something similar, but yours looks far better than mine. Thanks :-)

Comment: Can't help bike-shedding: `substrIndex = findIndex ("-}" \`isPrefixOf\`) . tails`... or maybe use [KMP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/KMP-0.1.0.2/docs/Data-Algorithms-KMP.html).